# SQL Select newest value Id from one table

Tags: sql

So we have an application that stores lap times for runners the tables are a bit like this.

**Runner** Table

```
ID|AGE|LastLap|BestLap
```

**Laps** Table

```
ID|Time|Date|Inserted|RunnerID
```

So are application had/has a bug in it that when you add a lap that was in the past from your last lap it still set the *last lap id* when it did not need to.

What I want to do is fix the `lastlap` column so that the true last lap id for each runner is the last lap id do by ordering laps table by Date for each runner but i can't figure out a SQL update script to do this. I get very close but I can't get the ID from the laps table or I get more than one result.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Use the `time` and `date` columns to get the last lap, not the `id`.  Clearly insertion order is not necessarily the same as chronological order.

Comment: You may want to post (using [edit]) your "*very close*" script anyway. This will improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be storing that information in the Runners table at all - make it a view, or a report, and draw the information from the Laps table on use. But if you don't have that choice - can you at least tell us what kind of SQL you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I'd follow Mike's statement: if it isn't some crazy performance-tuning thing, stick with a view for cases like "last..." "best...", it can minimize any hassle in this regard.

Anyways, if you "just" need to update what's broken, the following should work with MS SQL, if not great performance-wise. 
Presumptions: "time" is your business-value for the lap, not time of day; "inserted" and "ID" can't be used, because someone may insert data not ordered by date.

This means: if you have more then one lap-entry per runner per day, you just have to assume that the biggest ID has your desired business-value or change your data-model.

```
DECLARE @RunnerID INT;
SET @RunnerID = yourRunnerID;

UPDATE RUNNERS
SET LastLap = (SELECT MAX(L.ID)
                FROM Laps L 
                WHERE L.RunnerID = @RunnerID 
                AND L.DATE = (SELECT MAX(Date) 
                                FROM Laps 
                                WHERE Laps.RunnerID = @RunnerID
                              )
               )
WHERE ID = @RunnerID;
```